# Prolog predecessor math

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have an `add2` predicate which resolves like this where `s(0)` is the successor of `0` i.e `1`

```
?- add2(s(0)+s(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0)))))

?- add2(0, s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(0)))

?- add2(s(s(0)), s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0)))))
```

etc..

I'm trying to do add  in a predecessor predicate which will work like so

```
?- add2(p(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(0))

?- add2(0, s(p(0)), Z).
Z = 0

?- add2(p(0)+s(s(0)),s(s(0)),Z).
Z = s(s(s(0)))

?- add2(p(0), p(0)+s(p(0)), Z).
Z = p(p(0))
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this. My code is below.

```
numeral(0).
numeral(s(X)) :- numeral(X).
numeral(X+Y) :- numeral(X), numeral(Y).
numeral(p(X)) :- numeral(X).


add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).
add(p(X),Y,p(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).


resolve(0,0).
resolve(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    resolve(X,Y).
resolve(p(X),p(Y)) :-
    resolve(X,Y).
resolve(X+Y,Z) :-
    resolve(X,RX),
    resolve(Y,RY),
    add(RX,RY,Z).

add2(A,B,C) :-
    resolve(A,RA),
    resolve(B,RB),
    add(RA,RB,C).
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, adding with successor arithmetic means handling successor terms, which have the shape `0` or `s(X)` where `X` is also a successor term. This is addressed completely by this part of your code:

```
add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).
```

Now you have to make a decision; you can either handle the predecessors and the addition terms here, in `add/3`, or you can wrap this predicate in another one that will handle them. You appear to have chosen to wrap `add/3` with `add2/3`. In that case, you will definitely need to create a reducing term, such as you've built here with `resolve/2`, and I agree with your implementation of *part* of it:

```
resolve(0,0).
resolve(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    resolve(X,Y).
resolve(X+Y,Z) :-
    resolve(X,RX),
    resolve(Y,RY),
    add(RX,RY,Z).
```

This is all good. What you're missing now is a way to handle `p(X)` terms. The right way to do this is to notice that you already have a way of deducting by one, by using `add/3` with `s(0)`:

```
resolve(p(X), R) :-
    resolve(X, X1),
    add(s(0), R, X1).
```

In other words, instead of computing X using X = Y - 1, we are computing X using X + 1 = Y.

Provided your inputs are never negative, your `add2/3` predicate will now work.